# Extrusion stops during print

Tags: filament, pla, wanhao

I changed the filament (PLA) in my Wanhao Duplicator I3+. I ended the first try to print when I saw that the 'lines' were too thin. I re-sliced with a higher temperature (195°C instead of 190°C). Now the print started without a problem but after about 25% no more filament came out of the extruder. What can be the reason and how can I resolve it?

The filament is from Vertex, grey. The object that I use to test is a 20 mm hollow cube from Thingiverse that I have used for the previous filament too.

I am not sure that this is a clogging problem since the print starts with no problems. It just stopped after 25%. When I started another print I was able to finish by increasing the temperature.

Comment: You are probably experiencing clogging. Note that there are a few topics on that subject here on 3D Printing SE. Your question is a possible duplicate of [I'm getting a prusa i3, if I have a nozzle clog, can I easily get rid of it by simply replacing the nozzle?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5191/im-getting-a-prusa-i3-if-i-have-a-nozzle-clog-can-i-easily-get-rid-of-it-by-s); the accepted answer may be of interest for you.

Comment: Can clogging happen during printing? The printed part is of good quality now that I use a higher temperature. It just stopped all of a sudden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I redid the print in order to reply to some questions posed in the answer of @kdtop. The print started but the output was not consistent and sometimes stopped. The temperature is 195°C and sometimes 'drop' to 194°C. First I pushed the new real so that the extruder did not need to pull so much. When this did not solve the problem I changed the temperature to 200°C. Now the output became consistent and my print finished. It was not as good as the one that I did with my previous filament. The top was not as neatly closed. Only the last 2 layers covered more or less for 100% the surface (perhaps 200°C is too high for this?).

For me the solution is to higher the temperature to 200°C (or perhaps 205°C).

Comment: I have a Lutzbot Mini and use Cura. I noticed that my nozzle clogs if each layer is too small. If your cube is 20mm with thin walls, then I agree with you that the retraction may cause the feed to overheat, soften and clog. If you don't want to print at the higher temp, you can try printing with more detail. Sometimes that works. In general I also try to avoid small layers by printing multiple objects at once even though I'm sure I could tune the printer better.

Answer (score 1):

My slicer (Cura-lulzbot) has a setting for initial printing temp, and then printing temp after the first few layers.  Is it possible that your temp is initially OK, but then drops too low?  Does your printer have a readout that shows the current temp?  Is the temp still OK when it stops?

It sounds like you are printing a sample cube, so I assume not too large.  Could you simulate this by just directly command your printer to extrude 500 mm of filament, or longer?  Then see if it clogs.  That would tell you if it was a physical problem with your printer instead of some change specified by the G-code for a sliced print.

Comment: I will do a test with another object. The `gcode` is the same as before when the print finished correct.