# Why is my 3D printer not extruding properly?

Tags: print-quality, pla, troubleshooting, extrusion

I have a Duplicator i3 mini, which has yet to make it a month without breaking. This time it is extra broken because the filament is not extruding properly. the most successful print I've had yet had about a centimeter before turning into an absolute mess. I have a picture. It was not stringy, and had the exact shape i was trying to print, but was like a frame of a sort. I am printing with matterhackers MH build series PLA, which has worked before this started happening. What should I do? What troubleshooting steps should I take?[image: It's a mess]

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Underextrusion and clogs can also be caused by insufficient temperature in the hot end. You've not reference your temperatures, so consider to use a test model and print at different temperatures. Too low temps can result in the problem you present, while too hot temps will increase stringing and peculiar blobs on the print.

If your slicer changes print speed at the layer of destruction, it may also be too fast, which is related to temperatures. Simplify3D allows speed variation as well as temperature variation at selected layers, but it requires deliberate action on the part of the operator.

Comment: A perfect option to find the correct temperature and speed could be determined using a heat tower, see [How does one use a heat tower?](/q/7345). Note that retraction can also cause clogging and under-extrusion.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like underextrusion as a result of a clog. Try cleaning the nozzle or replacing it.

See this link for more information about clogged nozzles.
[If I have a nozzle clog, can I easily get rid of it by simply replacing the nozzle?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5191/if-i-have-a-nozzle-clog-can-i-easily-get-rid-of-it-by-simply-replacing-the-nozz)